# Simple way to check % of total if I add one criteria

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following script:

```
select count (*)
from somewhere
where 1=1
and criteria 1 = 'xxx' 
and criteria 2 = 'xx'  
and criteria 3 = 'x'
```

Is there a nice way to calculate the % of the count with the first 2 criterias vs the count with all 3 criterias ?

So far I'm using something that is not very elegant:

```
Select x.nb / y.nb
from
(select count (*) as nb
from somewhere
where 1=1
and criteria 1 = 'xxx' 
and criteria 2 = 'xx'  
and criteria 3 = 'x' ) x
JOIN
(select count (*) as nb
from somewhere
where 1=1
and criteria 1 = 'xxx' 
and criteria 2 = 'xx'  ) y on 1 = 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when criteria3 = 'x' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from somewhere
where criteria 1 = 'xxx' and criteria 2 = 'xx' ;
```

Or more concisely as:

```
select avg( (criteria3 = 'x')::int ) as ratio
from somewhere
where criteria 1 = 'xxx' and criteria 2 = 'xx' ;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed !!